# Basic request to mongodb with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

[image]

I need to get all objects inside "posts" that have "published: true"
with pymongo. I've tried already so many variants but all I can do:

```
for elt in db[collection].find({}, {"posts"}):
    print(elt)
```

And it'll show all "posts". I've tried smth like this:

```
for elt in db[collection].find({}, {"posts", {"published": {"$eq": True}}}):
    print(elt)
```

But it doesn't work. Help, I'm trying for 3 days already =\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to be doing is to use the aggregate [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) like so:

```
db[collection].aggregate([
   {
      "$match": { // only fetch documents with such posts
         "posts.published": {"$eq": True}
      }
   },
   {
      "$project": {
          "posts": {
             "$filter": {
                 "input": "$posts",
                 "as": "post",
                 "cond": {"$eq": ["$$post.published", True]}
              }
          }
      }
   }
])
```

Note that the currenct structure returned will be:

```
[
   {posts: [post1, post2]},
   {posts: [post3, post4]}
]
```

If you want to retrieve it as a list of posts you'll need to add an `$unwind` stage to flatten the array.

The query options are quite limited you can do it with [$elemMatch (projection)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) or with the `$` operator but both of these return only the first post that matches the condition which is not what you want.

------- EDIT --------

Realizing `posts` is actually an object and not an array, you'll have to turn the object to an array, iterate over to filter and then restore the structure like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "posts": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          $filter: {
            input: {
              "$objectToArray": "$posts"
            },
            as: "post",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$post.v.published",
                true
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6hg5pYIBm7k)

Comment: It returns: <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x0484E2B0>. And it's not iterable.

Comment: I had an extra `}` in the match condition. i edited my post to match. you can also view the example here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/yISGSH0Dvh1

Comment: Yes, I've noticed this, but it still doesn't work. I think the problem in missed level in your "Configuration". It should be between "posts" and "published"(ex. CGI2TQdBHnU key on my screenshot).

Comment: Oh, i just now noticed posts is an object and not an array.

Answer (score 1):

What I assumed that your document looks like this,

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5f8570f8afdefd2cfe7473a7"),
"posts" : {
    "a" : {
        "p" : false,
        "name" : "abhishek"
    },
    "k" : {
        "p" : true,
        "name" : "jack"
    },
    "c" : {
        "p" : true,
        "name" : "abhinav"
    }
}}
```

You can try the following query but the result format will be a bit different, adding that for clarification,

```
db.getCollection('temp2').aggregate([
{
     $project: {
        subPost: { $objectToArray: "$posts" }
     }
  },
{
    '$unwind' : '$subPost'
},
{
    '$match' : {'subPost.v.p':true}
},
{
    '$group': {_id:'$_id', subPosts: { $push:  { subPost: "$subPost"} }}    
}
])
```

result format,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f8570f8afdefd2cfe7473a7"),
    "subPosts" : [ 
        {
            "subPost" : {
                "k" : "k",
                "v" : {
                    "p" : true,
                    "name" : "jack"
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "subPost" : {
                "k" : "c",
                "v" : {
                    "p" : true,
                    "name" : "abhinav"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```